# How do I add multiple images in JSON to meet Google's schema.org requirements?

Tags: media, meta-tags

[The Google guidelines for article on schema.org](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article) state:

> For best results, provide multiple high-resolution images (minimum of
>   300,000 pixels when multiplying width and height) with the following
>   aspect ratios: 16x9, 4x3, and 1x1.

How do I do this in Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes a little while to set up but is pretty straightforward.

1. Download and install the [Image Widget Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_widget_crop) and [Schema.org Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/schema_metatag) modules.
2. Go to `admin/config/media/crop` and create three crop types: 1x1, 4x3, and 16x9.  Set the aspect ratios to 1:1, 4:3, and 16:9, and set a *hard limit* of height 696 and width 696 for all three as stated in Google's documentation.
3. Go to `admin/config/media/image-styles` and create three image styles, 1x1, 4x3, and 16x9, and each should use the effect **Manual crop** pointing to the *crop type* you created in step #2.
4. Go to `/admin/structure/media` and find your image type. Go to **Manage form display** and use the crop widget.  Require all three crops.
5. Go to `/admin/config/search/metatag/` and choose the content that includes the images.
6. For Schema.org Article, scroll down to **Image** and choose *ImageObject*. Enter the URLs as tokens.

For example, if your image styles are:

- `hero_16x9`
- `hero_4x3`
- `hero_1x1`

And your node contains an entity reference to the image you want to use in `field_ref_media_hero`, then you can enter the URLs separated by commas like this:

`[node:field_ref_media_hero:entity:field_media_image:hero_16x9:url], [node:field_ref_media_hero:entity:field_media_image:hero_4x3:url], [node:field_ref_media_hero:entity:field_media_image:hero_1x1:url]`